# How to get CSS to E-Mails back in Magento 1.9.1

Tags: css, email, magento, magento-1.9.1

Since the upgrade from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.1 my E-Mails are no longer styled. 
The CSS I entered in the template_styles Field ("Vorlagenstile") is no longer loaded.

I read about the new Feature here http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-responsive-email#email-css but i can't get this thing to load any CSS.

In addition the Preview lacks the standard `<html>, <body>`, ... etc. prefix. (I don't know if this was the case before the upgrade).

Any Ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Between that and formkey, I've got a few template rewrites to review before upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I overread something. You have to add

```
{{var non_inline_styles}}
```

to your E-Mail "Template Content" field.

Looks like this then:

```
{{var non_inline_styles}}
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/header-billing.phtml'}}
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <p>
                        <strong>Hallo {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()}}</strong>,<br/>
                       ...
```

So now I have to do this to all the 37 E-Mail Templates. Thanks Magento!!

Comment: Can you please update you answer with how to write inline css in that condition. I am facing issue in applying inline css

Comment: Since I use no inline css and sadly can't give you any advice I think you should start a new question on this.

Answer (score -1):

if your are a C#.net/VB.net programmer I suggest you to use [PreMailer.Net](https://github.com/milkshakesoftware/PreMailer.Net).

> C# Library for moving CSS to inline style attributes, to gain maximum
>   E-mail client compatibility.

It converts make html style tags into element inline styles.

Comment: Thanks, but i just want to restore the default functionality